# How to fetch the rest of the JSON string from a pagination API?

Tags: android, json, api

I need to fetch some data from an `API` and display the data in a `ListView`. I succeeded getting the `JSON string` from the API, but that's only part of the data, there is more. How can I fetch the rest of the `JSON`? Should it be handled at the client side? Should I use a different URL to fetch more data? Thank you in advance.

Comment: it might help to post some code...

Comment: Does your `API` support pagination?

Comment: It is the (Github API)<https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-that-a-user-has-received>.

Comment: You need to look at the "link" header in the HTTP response for the URL for the next page.

Comment: @Code-Guru How could I read the header? Is there a specific name in the header for the next page?Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Already posted an answer with a few more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the "link" header of the HTTP response. The example header in the GitHub documentation is

> Status: 200 OK
>       Link: <https://api.github.com/resource?page=2 >; rel="next"
>       X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
>       X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999

Note the "Link" which gives the URL for the next page of events.

I have only done this in Python, not Android, so I don't know the exact details. I suggest that you look at the [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html), [HttpResponse](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html), and [HttpMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html) docs. In particular, the [HttpMessage#getHeaders(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29) method looks promising.

If you are using [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), then you should look at [getHeaderField()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will be handled in client-side. Just change the page number in `API` url to get the next set of `JSON` data.

See the page attribute in url :

```
https://api.github.com/resource?page=2>;
```